# PySpark error when converting DF column to list

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with my Spark script.

I have dataframe 2, which is a single column dataframe. What I want to achieve is, returning only the results from df1 where the user is in the list.

I've tried the below, but get an error (also below)

Can anyone please advise?

```
    listx= df2.select('user2').collect()

    df_agg = df1\
        .coalesce(1000)\
        .filter((df1.dt == 20181029) &(df1.user.isin(listx)))\
        .select('list of fields')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keenek1/indev/rax.py", line 31, in <module>
    .filter((df1.dt == 20181029) &(df1.imsi.isin(listx)))\
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 444, in isin
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 36, in _create_column_from_literal
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [234101953127315]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
        at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Collect here is going to be very expensive? Why don't you just use `join`? `df_agg = df1.join(df2.selectExpr('user2 as user'), on='user', how='inner').where(...).select(...)`

Comment: @pault Good suggestion. He can use joins. Also, can you try using join on `[user]` with `'leftanti'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is the best answer but:

```
# two single column dfs to try replicate your example:
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([{'a': 10}])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([{'a': 10}, {'a': 18}])
l1 = df1.select('a').collect()
# l1 = [Row(a=10)]  - this is not an accepted value for the isin as it seems:
df2.select('*').where(df2.a.isin(l_x)).show()  # this will throw and error
df2.select('*').where(df2.a.isin([10])).show()  # this will NOT throw and error
```

So something like:

```
l2 = [item.a for item in l1]
# l2 = [10]
df2.where(F.col('a').isin(l2)).show()
```

(Which is a bit weird to be honest but... there is a ticket for supporting [isin with single column dataframes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23945?jql=text%20~%20%22pyspark%20isin%22))

Hope this helps, good luck!

**edit**: this is provided the collected list is a small one :)
Your example would be:

```
listx= [item.user2 for item in df2.select('user2').collect()]
df_agg = df1\
    .coalesce(1000)\
    .filter((df1.dt == 20181029) &(df1.user.isin(listx)))\
    .select('list of fields')
```